# VLOG doesn't work for Google Logging Library (glog)

Tags: c++, c++11, logging, glog

My purpose is simple: to somehow see the logs printed by VLOG(5), which is provided by the glog library.

I have the following code:

```
google::InitGoogleLogging(argv[0]);
google::ParseCommandLineFlags(&argc, &argv, true);
FLAGS_logtostderr = 1;
FLAGS_v = 10;
LOG(INFO) << "info"; // OK, I see it
LOG(WARNING) << "warning"; // OK
VLOG(5) << "vlog"; // Nothing :(
```

No matter I manually set the flags here (`FLAGS_logtostderr` and `FLAGS_v`) or I pass it through the command line (`--v=10`), I just never find the string "vlog" anywhere: neither stdout, stderr nor some log file under `\tmp`. I think I didn't change the output path though.

Do I miss anything here? Any idea how to enable `VLOG`?

Comment: It seems that the FLAGS_xxx stuff works only "If the Google gflags library is installed on your machine".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Personally, I've never tried it with

> FLAGS_logtostderr = 1;
>
> FLAGS_v = 10;

The VLOG works fine for me if I set "GLOG_v=x" as an environmental variable on both linux and windows. E.g.

Alternatively, if you want to test it on the command line you can do the following:

Windows:

`C:>set GLOG_v=5
C:>set GLOG_logtostderr=1
C:>YourProgramName`

Linux:

`$ GLOG_v=7 GLOG_logtostderr=1 ./YourProgramName`